# Finding Min/Max/Avg When Benchmarking Sorting Algorithms - Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, average

In my main method, included below, I run a Bubble Sort to sort an array with 10,000 random items. I use a for loop to sort this array a total of 100 times. I then output the total amount of time it takes the system to sort this random set of 10,000 integers.

Instead of outputting 100 different elapsed sorting times, I would like to simply output three numbers from this set of 100 elapsed times: 
 1) The avg amount of time it takes to sort 10,000 random integers using a bubble sort (simply     an average of the output)
 2) The minimum amount of time it took to sort the 10,000 random integers.
 3) The maximum amount of time it took to sort the 10,000 random integers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

Here is the main method I use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //run sorting algorithm a total of 100 times
    for (int k = 1; k<= 100; k++){
        int dataSz = 10000; //size of data set to be sorted
        int[] a = new int[dataSz]; //create array with dataSz new items
        int[] temp = new int [a.length]; //create empty temporary array with
        //same number of items as above array

        //fill the array with random integers
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            a[i] = (int) (Math.random()*100000+1);

        //get the start time in nanoseconds
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        //run Bubble Sort to sort the entire array
        bubbleSort(a);

        //get the end time in nanoseconds
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        //calculate elapsed time in nanoseconds
        long duration = endTime - startTime;

        //print the elapsed time in seconds (nanoseconds/1 billion)
        System.out.printf("%12.8f %n", (double)duration/100000000);
```

Here is what the system outputs after I run the program. *NOTE* I would like my avg, min and max to follow the same syntax as my current system output. Thanks.

```
run:
1.77562000 
1.54235000 
1.26343000
... continues for 100 
... total
... sorting durations
1.26230000 
1.26011000 
1.26398000 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the running times to a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)?

Comment: @ProgrammerDan No, I have never used a TreeSet before. I will look them up and see if they can be of assistance to my program.

Comment: You don't need to store each runtime, you can just calculate a [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)

Comment: @ProgrammerDan How would you go about adding the running times to a TreeSet?

Comment: @azurefrog has the best idea. Simply keep track of current minimum, and current maximum, and compute your average using a moving average. No TreeSet necessary. However, if you want to use a TreeSet, recall that for every primitive type, there is an Object type, and you should be able to work forward from there. You could compute more interesting statistics like median, mode, and standard deviation if you have the full statistics.

Comment: @azurefrog Exactly - I am looking to store each runtime. I am trying to figure out a way to find the avg, min and max of each runtime and output it to the system as a concise table.

Comment: Consider using Apache Commons Math, in particular `SummaryStatistics` and `DescriptiveStatistics` http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html

Comment: Was this the output you were looking for

Comment: For benchmarking, use ```new Random(0)```, not ```Math.random()```. It'll give you deterministic results.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the minimum and maximum is pretty straight forward-simply use two helper variables, one for minimum and one for maximum and update them on each new time you measure.

Computing the average is only slightly harder-again you need helper variable but this time you need two. Count the number of measurements you've done in the first one and store the accumulated time in the second one. Then computing the average is simple-divide the accumulated time by the number of measurements.